# Is it solvable? Six venn diagram problem. Very Complicated

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

It classifies 10000 people as

1. young or old
2. male or female
3. married or single

Of these 10000 people, 3000 are young, 4600 are male, 7000 are married
1320 = young and male, 3010 = married and male, 1400 = young and married
600 = young and married and male.

Y = young, O = old, M = male, F = female, W = married, S = single

Find **how many are young and female and single**.

---

Then I get

Y = 3000, O = 7000, M = 4600, F = 5400, W = 7000, S = 3000,

M and Y = 1320, M and W = 3010, Y and W = 1400,

F or O = 8680, F or S = 6990, O or F = 8600,

M and Y and W = 600, F or O or S = 9400

**Y and F and S** = ? (what we are looking for)

---

I need to find the intersection of Y and F and S

Y and F and S = 1000 - (O or M or W)

O or M or W = O + M + W - **O and M** - M and W - O and W + **O and M and W**

---

**but I failed to get any numbers related with O and the other.
How would I get it? This is solvable? I am stuck on this for several hours but can't think of any solution.**

Please help me~

Comment: I don't know how you can have 3,000 out of 1,000.

Comment: Did you mean to say that there are $10,000$ people in total?

Comment: I like how you used "very complicated" in the title.

Comment: Sorry it was 10000. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to find how many young females there are: there are 3000 young people, and 1320 young men.  So, there must be 1680 young women.

Now, there are 1400 people who are both young and married, and 600 that are young, married, and male; hence there are 800 people who are young, married, and female.

Finally, the number of young, female, single people is the number of young female people minus the number of young, female, married people; so, there must be $1680-800=880$ people who are young, female, and single.